# Compare very different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two `Tables` that are read from separate files (`.xlsx` and `.csv`) and are imported into MS Access. They are not in the same format
(which is why I'm having such a difficult time with it).

Here is `xlsxTable`:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    ID    |     Name     |    SSN    |    SSN2    |   Address                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 00012345 | Robert Robin | ThisIsSSN | ThisIsSSN2 | 12345 StreetName St. CityName, KS |
| 00013245 | Pete Peters  | ThisIsSSN | ThisIsSSN2 | 54321 StreetName St. CityName, MO |
| 00012358 | Mike Michaels| ThisIsSSN | ThisIsSSN2 | 69874 StreetName St. CityName, NY |
| 00098755 | Tim Timpson  | ThisIsSSN | ThisIsSSN2 | 15987 StreetName St. CityName, KY |
| 00035784 | Tom Thompson | ThisIsSSN | ThisIsSSN2 | 95123 StreetName St. CityName, CA |
| 00012584 | Will Willers | ThisIsSSN | ThisIsSSN2 | 35789 StreetName St. CityName, WA |
| ........ | ...........  | ......... | .......... | ................................. |
```

Here is my `csvTable`:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tracking_number   |   last_name   |   first_name   |  middle_name  |  suffix  | alias_last_name   |   alias_first_name   |    alias_middle_name   |   alias_suffix  |    number   |    number_type     |    dob     |    street   |     city     |  state  | zip  | country | phone |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            135247 |  Keeves       |   Michael      |               |  Jr      |                   |                      |                        |                 |  ThisIsSSN  | SSN/ITIN           |   1/1/1990 | StreetName  |   CityName   |    NJ   |      |   US    |       |
|            135248 |  Jackson      |   Sue          |    Master     |          |                   |                      |                        |                 |  ThisIsSSN  | SSN/ITIN           | 10/29/1980 | StreetName  |   CityName   |    NY   | zip  |   US    |       |
|            135248 |  Thomspon     |   Dolf         |    Laundry    |          |                   |                      |                        |                 |  DriverNum  | Driver'sLicense    | 11/15/1962 | StreetName  |   CityName   |    KS   |      |   US    |       |
|            135249 |  Peters       |   Pete         |               |          |    Peters         |     Petey            |                        |                 |  ThisIsSSN  | SSN/ITIN           |   5/6/1975 | StreetName  |   CityName   |    PA   | zip  |   US    |       |
|            135250 |  Rogers       |   Steve        |               |          |                   |                      |                        |                 |  ThisIsSSN  | SSN/ITIN           | 12/25/1990 | StreetName  |   CityName   |    CT   | zip  |   US    |       |
|            135250 |  Nikolson     |   Jack         |               |  Jr      |                   |                      |                        |                 |  DriverNum  | Driver'sLicense    |   8/5/1975 | StreetName  |   CityName   |    CA   | zip  |   US    |       |
|            135251 |  Keeves       |   Keanu        |    Neo        |          |                   |                      |                        |                 |  ThisIsSSN  | SSN/ITIN           | 10/30/2000 | StreetName  |   CityName   |    TX   | zip  |   US    |       |
|            135252 |  Starch       |   Tony         |               |          |                   |                      |                        |                 |  ThisIsSSN  | SSN/ITIN           |  9/10/1975 | StreetName  |   CityName   |    NJ   |      |   US    |       |
|...................|...............|................|...............|..........|...................|......................|........................|.................|.............|....................|............|.............|..............|.........|......|.........|.......|
| dba_name          |   number      |   number_type  |  incorporated |  street  |       city        |        state         |        zip             |    country      |    phone    |                    |            |             |              |         |      |         |       |
| Mini Mart         |   92585487    |   EIN          |               |  Street  |      CityName     |        state         |        zipNum          |    GT           |             |                    |            |             |              |         |      |         |       |
|                   |   15987548    |   EIN          |               |  street  |      CityName     |        KS            |        zipNum          |    US           |             |                    |            |             |              |         |      |         |       |
| Check Systems     |   35854855    |   EIN          |               |  street  |      CityName     |        CA            |        zipNum          |    US           |             |                    |            |             |              |         |      |         |       |
|...................|...............|................|...............|..........|...................|......................|........................|.................|.............|....................|............|.............|..............|.........|......|.........|.......|
```

Where `dba_name` is in the above table is an actual row. For some reason, there's another portion of the file that starts a new list.

I have to query these tables and if a name along with SSN match, then I must take the name, address and SSN, and do something with them (most likely put into another table for export). I have loaded both tables from the files necessary. 
I'm now needing to iterate through and find the matches. For the sake of the sample data, `Pete Peters` should match here since the data is in both tables. My expected output should look a lot like the first table:

```
|    ID    |     Name     |    SSN    |    SSN2    |   Address                         |
```

I currently have an MS Access database that contains these tables. Though, with how the data is parsed, I'm not sure where to even start with the SQL. Performance-wise, this may be extensive. I'm just looking for a way to get it working first.

How can I query these two very different tables and only pull the data that matches?

Comment: Use a library like EPPlus, it will make your life easier: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

Comment: @Ozkan , Thank you. I'll have to look into it. I attempted to use Entity Framework for another project but was never able to get it to work or make sense

Comment: First off fix your csv file problem. I think it probably occurs because your csv is malformed, or has too many commas on some lines, or a comma is escaped when it shouldn’t be or isn’t escaped when it should be. To know for sure you’d have to upload the entire file somewhere so we can take a look at it

Comment: @symon I don’t think EPPlus will help, it’s for reading and writing xlsx files but you don’t necessarily seem to have any problem with your xlsx file- the csv is the bigger problem, and then your problems would probably be easiest solved in a database. Do you have to use access? It’s a bit lame compared to the free sqlserver provisions these and the only reason I can foresee anyone would carry on using it is for legacy compatibility with an existing system

Comment: You mean in regards to seemingly having two tables in the same file for my CSV? Instead of looking for an (non)escaped character, might it be easier to just parse it and place it into another `DataTable` then add it to a `DataSet` and return the set? (Just popped into my head as opposed to uploading the information somewhere) -- For using Access, yes. While I do have SQL Server, this is all an extension to a previously made Access form. Creating a new database *just* for this in SQL Server didn't seem to come across as "reasonable". Though, I'm not entirely opposed to it.

Comment: If your csv is two different “tables” in one file then for sure I’d split them out and treat them consistently.. were this my project i’d have two or three tables, load all the data from the files into the database and then get the db to associate the data together

Comment: Sql server is a lot nicer to work with, and creating database and tables in it is relatively trivial. For sure stick with access if you want to tho. If your concern is over creating tables, there are lots of websites (like sqlfiddle.com) that you can just paste some example data into and they will guess at the CREATE TABLE statement necessary- from what you’ve posted there’s it would take me about 3 minutes to create tables in my local sql server (not as many sites support things like his, for access because it’s not a pro grade solution)

Comment: SQL is definitely my weak point. While, I'm not opposed to using it, it just seems like a step in the oppose direction if all the data is in Access- if that makes sense

Comment: Erm. I thought the data was in xlsx and csv files? If this data is already in a database then preparing it for export is easier than reading it from file, translating/associating it in c#, etc

Comment: Pulled **from** xlsx and cvs, yes. I was meaning that everything that will use this data is in Access. And importing them as-is is doable, though with Access's limitations, it seemed better to do everything with C# and then import the results if there are any matches

Comment: Oh, yeah, I wouldn’t bother with c#, I’d get access to import them (you already know how to do this?) into staging (temp) tables in access, then ask us how to write a query that turns the staged data into something that you actually want in the proper tables in your db.. then empty the crap data out of the staging tables again ready for the next import

Comment: @CaiusJard , oh lorde. Well that *does* seem like the way to go about it. I must've been *way* over thinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access has a find duplicates query wizard.  The fastest way to handle the problem is to combine the tables manually or using 1 or more queries and then run the wizard.  Again, get all your data into one table and then run the wizard.  To make things complicated by breaking them down.
you might get the data from the CSV Table: with a query like:

```
SELECT csvTable.First_Name AS First_Name, csvTable.Last_Name AS Last_Name, csvTable.Number AS [Number]
FROM csvTable
GROUP BY csvTable.First_Name, csvTable.Last_Name, csvTable.Number
HAVING (((Count(csvTable.Number))>1));
```

then create a query with the same structure from the xlsx table:

```
SELECT Left([xlsxTable]![FullName],InStr([xlsxTable]![FullName]," ")) AS First_Name, Right([xlsxTable].[FullName],Len([xlsxTable].[FullName])-InStr([xlsxTable]![FullName]," ")) AS Last_Name, xlsxTable.SSN AS [Number]
FROM xlsxTable
GROUP BY Left([xlsxTable]![FullName],InStr([xlsxTable]![FullName]," ")), Right([xlsxTable].[FullName],Len([xlsxTable].[FullName])-InStr([xlsxTable]![FullName]," ")), xlsxTable.SSN
HAVING (((Count(xlsxTable.SSN))>1));
```

The having Count >1 does the work of finding the duplicates.  Most of the rest of this is obtuse string manipulations to turn Full Name into first and last name directly in the sql. Then combine the queries so you can run them at the same time in the sql pane using a UNION ALL statement:

```
SELECT csvTable.First_Name AS First_Name, csvTable.Last_Name AS Last_Name, csvTable.Number AS [Number]
FROM csvTable
GROUP BY csvTable.First_Name, csvTable.Last_Name, csvTable.Number

UNION ALL 
SELECT Left([xlsxTable]![FullName],InStr([xlsxTable]![FullName]," ")) AS First_Name, Right([xlsxTable].[FullName],Len([xlsxTable].[FullName])-InStr([xlsxTable]![FullName]," ")) AS Last_Name, xlsxTable.SSN AS [Number]
FROM xlsxTable
GROUP BY Left([xlsxTable]![FullName],InStr([xlsxTable]![FullName]," ")), Right([xlsxTable].[FullName],Len([xlsxTable].[FullName])-InStr([xlsxTable]![FullName]," ")), xlsxTable.SSN;
```

union all keeps duplicates while union omits them.  I have removed the having statements from the union as I find it works better.  next use the find duplicates wizard on your combined query like:

```
SELECT [combine tables].First_Name, [combine tables].Last_Name, [combine tables].Number
FROM [combine tables]
GROUP BY [combine tables].First_Name, [combine tables].Last_Name, [combine tables].Number
HAVING (((Count([combine tables].Number))>1));
```

Comment: I'll give this a go- Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad this helped.  I was afraid it wasn't clear enough.